# Are there devices which convert thermal energy to electric energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, phonons

Converting optical energy to electric energy is a huge business based on the photovoltaic effect. Is there an analogous effect for phonons? Are ther devices which convert phonon energy to electric energy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect). The Seebeck effect, for example, is the direct conversion of thermal gradient to electric voltage. It is used in the small scale in [thermocouples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple) to measure temperatures electronically, or in the larger scales in [thermoelectric generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator) for power generation.

In fact, many of the long-range space probes launched by NASA get power this way. [Radioactive material](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) generates heat on decay, which gets converted to electricity, which then allows probes like [Voyager 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_2) to have power faraway from the sun where solar power is not available.

Comment: I am seeking an effect which does not require temperature gradient. Can a device be built which captures "flying" phonons and convert them to electric energy without the need for a colder surface? I am aware that such an idea may violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics, but I wish to know from a technological perspective why this is (not) feasible.

Comment: @Tarek: So you seek something that you already know doesn't exist!?

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Piezo-electric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity#Mechanism)?

if I'm not mistaken, pressure on the crystal is in essence equal to long-wavelength phonons.

If that's not what you're after, perhaps read [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=convert%20phonons&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.me.gatech.edu%2Ffiles%2Fnsf_onr_2012%2Fkeynote%2FKeynote%2520Kaviany.pdf&ei=oNj-T5ygHIbC0QW1p_GOBw&usg=AFQjCNEdy5w34LfxHmmQ9ATbKXvfVN0zVQ&cad=rja), or else [this](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v432/n7015/abs/nature03046.html) paper (both the result of a 5 minute Google scholar session).

They're don't seem to contain exactly what you're after (haven't read them thoroughly though), but are related nonetheless. At least they are a hint that a workable device to convert short-wavelength phonons to electrical energy is currently only available on the nano-scale.